# How to print UNICODE string in GDB when debugging in Windows?

Tags: windows, unicode, gdb, mingw

I want to display UNICODE strings in Windows using either `p` or `x`.

**Edit:**

The UNICODE string I'm examining is one of type `PWSTR`.

In this case EAX points to the starting address of the string "base.exe":

```
(gdb) x /16xb $eax
0x8e1c88:       0x62    0x00    0x61    0x00    0x73    0x00    0x65    0x00
0x8e1c90:       0x2e    0x00    0x65    0x00    0x78    0x00    0x65    0x00
```

Now issuing the following command to change to target-charset doesn't help much:

```
(gdb) set target-charset UTF-16
(gdb) show target-charset
The target character set is "UTF-16".

(gdb) x /s $eax
0x8e1c88:       <incomplete sequence \142>

(gdb) x /30s $eax
0x8e1c88:       <incomplete sequence \142>
0x8e1c8a:       <incomplete sequence \141>
0x8e1c8c:       <incomplete sequence \163>
0x8e1c8e:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c90:       <incomplete sequence \056>
0x8e1c92:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c94:       <incomplete sequence \170>
0x8e1c96:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c98:       ""
0x8e1c99:       ""
```

Trying the LE version doesn't fix things either:

```
(gdb) show target-charset
The target character set is "UTF-16LE".


(gdb) x /30s $eax
0x8e1c88:       <incomplete sequence \142>
0x8e1c8a:       <incomplete sequence \141>
0x8e1c8c:       <incomplete sequence \163>
0x8e1c8e:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c90:       <incomplete sequence \056>
0x8e1c92:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c94:       <incomplete sequence \170>
0x8e1c96:       <incomplete sequence \145>
0x8e1c98:       ""
0x8e1c99:       ""
```

However, for UTF-8 things start to work a little:

```
(gdb) set target-charset UTF-8
(gdb) x /s $eax
0x8e1c88:       "b"
(gdb) x /30s $eax
0x8e1c88:       "b"
0x8e1c8a:       "a"
0x8e1c8c:       "s"
0x8e1c8e:       "e"
0x8e1c90:       "."
0x8e1c92:       "e"
0x8e1c94:       "x"
0x8e1c96:       "e"
```

**How can I make GDB interpret the codes properly to display the whole string at once using e.g. `x /s`?**

The problem as it stands now is that GDB sees `0x62 0x00` as "b" followed by a null-byte (terminating character)...

Thank you,

Comment: Try `print (wchar_t*)$eax`

Comment: Also `x /sh $eax`.

Comment: @monkeyman79 `x /sh whatever` works for me. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Print `x /sh $eax` to see Unicode string in EAX register.